# How do I make a linux image which is of my current system?

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, distributions

I want a really minimalistic version of Linux to run on my raspberry pi. I need nothing on it apart form the tools to make it work. I can then install the things I need such as python, nano, ssh etc.

Is there a version of Linux like that? I was thinking Ubuntu snappy but wasn't too sure.

Secondly. If I got it configured exactly how I wanted on my system, is it possible to convert it make to a .img file so that I could flash it onto an SD card to use exactly the same settings on 3/4 of my raspberry Pi s?

Answer (score 1):

It will be much quicker if you just download one of the existing images for Raspberry Pi (from the distribution of your choice).

You start with a working image and you never have to worry about how to get a setup to a bootable image. You can uninstall and install until you have the system as you want it and then you can just make a backup copy of the SD, and you will have an base image that you can work with for the other Pis.

Comment: I'm sure this would work but it's not the way I want to do it. I want to just start with a barely working version of Linux and turn it into what I need. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The [Arch ARM image](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/raspberry-pi) is probably one of the leanest available:

You can set it up and, when you are satisfied with it, copy it to transfer to your other SD cards using `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb conv=sync,noerror bs=1M | gzip  >/mnt/yourbackuplocation/rpi.img.gz
```

Restore it with:

```
gunzip -c /mnt/yourbackuplocation/rpi.img.gz | dd of=/dev/sdb conv=sync,noerror count=7580 bs=1M iflag=fullblock
```

Comment: Thats seems like a good version to use. IS that the most minimalistic version available? Is it possible to save my OS as a .img file instead of copying everything over? Then I can just flash it over. If I had set up the OS so it had some scripts on and automatically ran them on boot would that be transferred over as well? Thanks

Comment: @cross Is it the most minimal? I have no idea; I haven't tried them all, but it ships with a lean set of packages (no X, for example). The method I suggested does save it as a compressed image...

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much for your help. I'll give this ago. Another quick question. Could I configure the OS on a virtual machine on my MAC then boot it up onto the RPI after?

Comment: @cross Sure: assuming the virtualised environment is ARMv6.

Comment: How would I set that up? Is parallels ARMv6? Is VirtualBox ARMv6? Or do you mean the actual OS needs to be ARMv6? Thanks for answering my questions.

Comment: @cross You need to be able to run an ARMv6 machine in VirtualBox (or whatever virtualisation tool you use). I have no idea how easy/possible that is).

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your help. I'll research it. Thanks.